# Flatten dynamic json in ADF with schema drift enabled at sournce

Tags: json, azure, scala, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have an issue with ADF where I have to read dynamic json as I have enabled schema drift in my source.

To flatten the json I am coding it as array(byName('Columnname')) in unroll by dynamic content section. Here columnname is the array which need to be unrolled. I am getting this error -

{"message":"Job failed due to reason: at : scala.MatchError: array(byName('Columname')) (of class com.microsoft.dataflow.FunctionNode). Details:scala.MatchError: array(byName('Columname')) (of class com.microsoft.dataflow.FunctionNode)\n\tat com.microsoft.dataflow.transformers.FoldDownUtils$.unstackUnrollByRecurse(FoldDown.scala:79)\n\tat

Kindly help as to how to unroll array of dynamic json with schema drift option enabled at source.

Comment: Looks like the expression you are using is wrong or don't matches your data. Could you share a sample json file like what you are using.

Comment: As you have used **byName** in your expression that means you are selecting single column, so you should type cast it to string or long not array. Using **byNames()** func can use array. Check this document for more information on the [meta-functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#metafunctions).